# Issue with InsertOnly command in Ormlite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using the Servicestack.ormlite package. Everything has been working perfectly, but last night, all of a sudden, my InsertOnly command stopped working. This is the format of the InsertOnly command I am using, straight from the docs: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

```
Here is the command:
DB.InsertOnly(new ppNomination
{
    PortalID = clientID,
    NOM_sOtherExperience = nom.Title,
    NOM_sExperienceDescription = nom.Description,
    NOM_nWitness = nom.Witness,
    NOM_dLastUpdated = DateTime.Now,
    NOM_WrittenBy = nom.WrittenBy,
    NOM_nSteward = nom.Nominee,
    NOM_dDeliveredOn = nom.DeliveredOn,
    NOM_dCreatedOn = nom.CreatedOn,
    NOM_nApprovedBy = nom.ApproverId == -1 ? (int?)null : nom.ApproverId,
    NOM_lActive = nom.Active,
    NOM_lResubmitted = nom.IsResubmitted,
    NOM_lReturned = nom.IsReturned,
    NOM_lManagerApproved = nom.IsManagerApproved
     },

a => a.Insert(p => new { p.PortalID, p.NOM_sOtherExperience, p.NOM_sExperienceDescription, 
                        p.NOM_nWitness, p.NOM_dLastUpdated, p.NOM_WrittenBy, p.NOM_nSteward,                     p.NOM_dDeliveredOn, 
                        p.NOM_dCreatedOn, p.NOM_nApprovedBy, p.NOM_lActive, p.NOM_lResubmitted, p.NOM_lReturned, 
                        p.NOM_lManagerApproved }));
```

nom is the object being passed to the function, and I am just filling it up. This is the error I see:
variable 'p' of type 'Obsidian.Domain.DomainModel.ppNomination' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?